# Issue with Advance Featured Products Extension in Magento 1.4.2

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I have issue in installing & using Advanced Featured Products Extension(http://www.mage-world.com/advance-featured-products-magento-extension ).

I followed the readme.txt (copied the files and created attribute for featured items) in the module.
But when I got to Goto admin->system->configuration , I am supposed find “Featured Products” option.

But I could not see that in system -> configuration menu. I tried clearing the cache & log in again, but still the Admin menu for Featured products is not appearing.

Has anybody faced similar issue. Any solution for this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few guesses (on a general extension installation note):

- Make sure that your file permissions are correct (make them match other working modules)
- Verify that you have copied the module XML file into app/etc/modules/
- Check in the backend under System -> Configuration -> Advanced for an entry for your module (it should be present and enabled)
- Once this is the case, clear out all your magento caches
- Log out and in (I know you tried this)

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: I found giving write permission to app, media and skin folders again worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, if you're using a memcache backend you need to click the 'flush cache storage' too.